# Аннотации для класса Spring framework

Tags: java, spring

В чём будет разница между следующими аннотациями при установке их в классе: `@Component`, `@Service` и `@Configuration`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Configuration обычно указывается для тех классов, в которых присутствуют аннотации @Bean. Таким образом позволяет создавать "конфигурации" для генерации различных бинов в рантайме, часто использующие фабрики. Это может быть например настройка подключения к бд или прочие бины, которые требуют настроек подключений и т.п. 
@Component и @Service по большому счету делают одно и тоже. Тут, скорее, дело в DDD. То есть если у вас приложение использует "компонентное" разбиение, то можно использовать @Component. Если при разработке ориентация на "сервисы", то можно использовать @Service. А вообще, прежде чем задавать вопросы, всегда лучше начинать с первоисточников, то есть официальной документации, по спрингу, в данном случае :)